# Silverlight, EF4, WCF RIA: An object with a null EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context?

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

First of all I wanted to thank you all for your effort and input. Stack Overflow has been the go-to resource for me, I feel that I've learned more in this forum than the entire 4 years at my college!

So onto the question. I have a Silverlight 4 project using EF and WCF RIA. 
In one of my pages I retrieve the contents of a table via a Ria web service call and store the result in an `ObservableCollection<T>`

SILVERLIGHT CODE:

```
//class variables;
public ObservableCollection<Data> DataSource { get; set; }   //Data entity
public ApplicationDomainContext Context { get; set; } //Ria Service

...
EntityQuery<Data> query = this.Context.GetDatasQuery();
this.Context.Load(query, loadedCallBack =>
{
   if( loadedCallBack.HasError )
   {
       loadedCallBack.MarkErrorAsHandled();
       MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve the desired data...");
       return;
   }

   this.DataSource = new ObservableCollection<Data>(loadedCallback.Entities);
}

...
private void CreateUserAction()
{
    string userName = WebContext.Current.User.Name;
    this.Context.CreateUserAction(userName, this.DataSource, callBack =>
    {
        if(callBack.HasError)
        {
            callBack.MarkErrorAsHandled();
            MessageBox.Show("Error creating user action");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

SERVICE CODE:

```
public partial class ApplicationDomainService :  LinqToEntitiesDomainService<ApplicationDomainModel> 
{
    [Invoke]
    public void CreateUserAction(string userName, IEnumerable<Data> dataItems)
    {
        foreach(Data dataItem in dataItems)
        {
            if( dataItem.EntityState == EntityState.Detached )
            {
                this.ObjectContext.Attach(dataItem); //ERROR???
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

So the code executes to the inside the `if( dataItem.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)` and gives me an error when I try to attach the object:

`An object with a null EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context.`

What's funny is that I do not modify the Data objects at all, and they do arrive with an Id and everything else on the client side.

If anyone can point me in the direction of what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it!!!

Thanks
`Martin, aka <bleepzter/>`

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the object once you attach it?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the latest version of RIA and EF yet, but you might want to try the following changes:

Change this:

```
    this.ObjectContext.Attach(dataItem);
```

To this:

```
    this.ObjectContext.Data.AttachAsModified(dataItem)
```

Data may be pluralized on the ObjectContext depending on your settings.

Comment: Ok, I tried this and it worked. To an Extent! Entities got added twice!

Comment: Did you write the CreateUserAction method or was it generated with the service class?

Comment: I wrote it. That's why the service has a `public partial` in it's declaration. The actual service was generated by the DomainService prompts in VS2010, whereas the function of the service that I am having an issue with resides in a different file.

Comment: Yep, the generated service class should have **public partial** now too.  The reason I asked was the `LinqToEntitiesDomainService` inheritance. Is it necessary for you to explicitly Attach the entities?  If this is an insert, I would just add the new entities to the collection and call `SubmitChanges` from the client or `SaveChanges` from the service layer.